# Returning looped API call values using Observables in Angular

Tags: angular, api, asynchronous, rxjs, observable

I am trying to get a loop to return an API call. Using Spotify API I can generate the id of an artist from the name, so earlier in the code I've generated a list of names, held in an array. For my testing purposes, I'm using a dummy array of the same values a previous API call would return.

```
  getAllSpotifyArtistIds(){
    let dummyArtistList = ['loren north', 'Randy Emata', 'Dyekho', 'The Lemon Twigs', 'The Toasters'];
    for (let i = 0; i < dummyArtistList.length; i++) {
      this.artistToQuery = dummyArtistList[i];
      this.generateArtistIdFromArtist(dummyArtistList[i]).subscribe((response) => {
      this.newProperty.push(response); //this is a class property I'm hoping to populate with this response.
      })
    }
  }
```

the function generateArtistIdFromArtist(artistName: string) returns a single value each time it's called, which is the artist ID queried from Spotify's API.

The code for generating the Arist ID from spotify is as follows:

```
  generateArtistIdFromArtist(artistName){
    return this.spotifyService.getToken().pipe( 
      flatMap((accessTokenResponse) => {
        return this.spotifyService.searchArtistID(artistName, accessTokenResponse.access_token)
        .map((response) => {
          response.artists.items.forEach((spotifyArtist) => {
            this.spotifyArtistListFromQuery.push(spotifyArtist.name);
          });
          const artistMatchIndexPosition = this.spotifyArtistListFromQuery.findIndex((artistToQueryNow) => {
            return artistToQueryNow === artistName;
          });
          //Spotify returns multiple artists with similar names, so check for identical match
          if (artistMatchIndexPosition >= 0 ){
             this.artistIdListFromSpotify.push(response.artists.items[artistMatchIndexPosition].id)
             return response.artists.items[artistMatchIndexPosition].id;
                // finally return the id of the artist if there's a match
          }
        });
      })
    );
  }
```

I've tried putting setTimeout()'s in, in various places, but I think I just don't understand async coding well enough to really know what I'm doing. I thought maybe forcing some pauses might let the loop catch up. I only get 3 values back, at this point.

I'm expecting the Spotify results to be returned per artist in the dummyArtistList, but it's only returning a few, and they're incorrect somehow.

This works perfectly if you pass a single name into it, but the loop fails if you start doing more than one, and on three it gives completely wrong results. I'm new to coding and especially async, so I'm having a hard time understanding why I can't get the loop to wait for the API call to complete with observables. I'm sure it's something to do with the fact that the loop itself isn't async, and the API call is, any help sorting that out would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an array of observable, the concat operator from rxjs and subscribing to it. Read more about concat [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/concat.html).

You can import concat like this:

> import { concat } from 'rxjs/operators';

```
  getAllSpotifyArtistIds() {
    const APICallArray = [];
    const dummyArtistList = ['loren north', 'Randy Emata', 'Dyekho', 'The Lemon Twigs', 'The Toasters'];

    for (let i = 0; i < dummyArtistList.length; i++) {
        this.artistToQuery = dummyArtistList[i];
        APICallArray.push(this.generateArtistIdFromArtist(dummyArtistList[i]));
     }
     concat(...APICallArray).subscribe((res) => {
         res.map((response) => {
            response.artists.items.forEach((spotifyArtist) => {
              this.spotifyArtistListFromQuery.push(spotifyArtist.name);
            });

            const artistMatchIndexPosition = this.spotifyArtistListFromQuery.findIndex((artistToQueryNow) => {
                return artistToQueryNow === artistName;
            });
            if (artistMatchIndexPosition >= 0 ) {
                this.artistIdListFromSpotify.push(response.artists.items[artistMatchIndexPosition].id);
                this.newProperty.push(response.artists.items[artistMatchIndexPosition].id);
            }
        });
     });
}

  generateArtistIdFromArtist(artistName) {
        return this.spotifyService.getToken().pipe(
          flatMap((accessTokenResponse) => {
            return this.spotifyService.searchArtistID(artistName, accessTokenResponse.access_token);
                 })
        );
    }
```

Comment: interesting, I'll try that now!

Comment: I'm getting the following error

ERROR in src/app/home/home.component.ts(118,31): error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'UnaryFunction<Observable<{}>, Observable<{}>>'.

Is this because the return from generateArtistIdFromArtist(foo) is actually a string instead of an observable? I'm guessing I should have it return an observable?

Comment: Yes, it seems so, generateArtistIdFromArtist should returns an observable that you can subscribe in concat response.

Comment: @Ritesh, You should clearly mention what is `concat` here. It should be imported from rxjs. `import { concat } from 'rxjs/operators';`

Comment: @AmitChigadani, He is already using a bunch of rxjs operators. It should not be a big deal to figure this out. We are not here for spoon feeding.

Comment: Yes, but that is the key point of your answer. Using `concat` operator from `rxjs`. You should also keep in mind that your answers are going to help future readers as well.

Comment: @Ritesh I'm actually super new to this, so that's my first time ever seeing concat. I've been googling it. Hate to say it but spoon feeding would be greatly appreciated here only because I started using observables for the first time ever last week.

Comment: @AmitChigadani I've imported concat, thank you for that, I was able to find it through googling. As I understand it, it executes a series of operations for observables? 

I've verified my first function is returning observables, and creating an array of Observables at this point, but I can't get the .subscribe() to work. Any pointers?

Comment: @Ritesh thanks! I can't get the subscribe to work on the concat() array :-/ It's definitely got observables in it at this point, I've verified that.

Comment: @glitchwizard: Please check the updated answer. I have modified the generateArtistIdFromArtist to return an observable instead of an string and subscribing to that in concat subscribing.

Comment: @Ritesh I've tried your solution, but unfortunately I'm still getting the following error: "error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'UnaryFunction<Observable<{}>, Observable<{}>>'."

It's talking about "concat(...APICallArray).subscribe(foo)".

That's strange because in the RxJS documentation, it seems like that should work.... but I'm stumped again at this point, I was trying to solve it more last night as well and still hitting a wall. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively do this using [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html), because you want to have all the results in an array.

Save all your `observables` in a temporary array and subscribe to it using `forkJoin` operator

```
getAllSpotifyArtistIds(){
    let dummyArtistList = ['loren north', 'Randy Emata', 'Dyekho', 'The Lemon Twigs', 'The Toasters'];
    let artistSet = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < dummyArtistList.length; i++) {
      this.artistToQuery = dummyArtistList[i];
      artistSet.push(this.generateArtistIdFromArtist(dummyArtistList[i]))
    }
     forkJoin(...artistSet).subscribe((response) => {
          //Here response is an array and you can simply assign
          this.newProperty = response;
     })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Ritesh's help, I was able to figure out how to solve this.

The final two functions are

```
  generateArtistIdFromArtist(artistName) {
      return this.spotifyService.getToken().pipe(
        flatMap((accessTokenResponse) => {
          return this.spotifyService.searchArtistID(artistName, accessTokenResponse.access_token);
               })
      );
  }
```

and then returning an array of information containing artists, using this call, the APICallArray itself actually had the information to it, no need to subscribe apparently. I still don't understand fully what's producing this, but I am able to get all the answers.

```
  getAllSpotifyArtistIds() {
    const APICallArray = [];
    const dummyArtistList = ['loren north', 'Randy Emata', 'Dyekho', 'The Lemon Twigs', 'The Toasters'];
    const ArtistOutputArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < dummyArtistList.length; i++) {
      this.artistToQuery = dummyArtistList[i];
      APICallArray.push(this.generateArtistIdFromArtist(dummyArtistList[i]));
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < APICallArray.length; i++) {
        APICallArray[i].subscribe((response) => {
          ArtistOutputArray.push(response);
        });
    }
    return ArtistOutputArray;
  }
```

Thank you @Ritesh!